# Software for burning AAC files to MP3 CDs?

Tags: itunes, audio, mp3, cd-burning

iTunes is lacking some features I could really use for burning MP3 CDs for the car audio system.

1. Ability to convert AAC to MP3
2. Ability to group non-album songs into folders

In itunes, the process appears to be:

- find all the songs you want to burn to an MP3 CD
- figure out which songs are not in MP3 format
- tell itunes to make duplicate versions of these files in MP3 format
- figure out which are now the MP3 versions and drag them into a playlist
- edit the copied MP3s' meta data to 'fake' a new album so it's grouped on the CD correctly

Is there a piece of software that can do what I'm looking for and/or is there a way to do what I want in iTunes that I'm somehow missing?

Answer (score 1):

If you change the Import CD As... to MP3, you should be able to convert any non-MP3 files to MP3. The same applies to all the supported file types.

Comment: I'm not importing a CD. I'm trying to create a CD. Does that setting have a bearing on burning a CD?

Answer (score 0):

[MP3 CD Maker](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mp3-cd-maker/id820390388?mt=12) would appear to do exactly what you want.

I haven't tested it & one of the reviews [somewhat illiterate, so pinch of salt may be required] said it didn't work - but it looks like it's free to try, 10 bucks to buy, so I guess you can test it first.

Comment: I will give it a try!